# XGBoost, Create DMatrix from One Row of Data in CSR Format

Tags: java, sparse-matrix, xgboost

I am reading [the documentation for XGBoost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/java_intro.html), and in particular, creating a DMatrix in CSR / CSC format.  The documentation is not very helpful:

```
To load sparse matrix in CSR/CSC format is a little complicated, 
the usage is like : suppose a sparse matrix : 1 0 2 0 4 0 0 3 3 1 2 0
```

It is not clear what is meant by the suppose above, it is also unclear how this maps to the standard Yale format `A, IA, JA` vectors.  So I tried loading the first row from the Agaricus test data set (in libSVM format)

```
0 1:1 9:1 19:1 21:1 24:1 34:1 36:1 39:1 42:1 53:1 56:1 65:1 69:1 77:1 86:1 88:1 92:1 95:1 102:1 106:1 117:1 122:1
```

I created a DMatrix as follows:

```
DMatrix dMatrix = new DMatrix(new long[] {0}, 
   new int[] {1, 9, 19, 21, 24, 34, 36, 39, 42, 53, 56, 65, 69, 77, 86, 88, 92, 95, 102, 106, 117, 122}, 
   new float[] {1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f},
   DMatrix.SparseType.CSC, 1);
```

But this does not give any kind of sensible answer it should be about 4.941254E-4 but it gives 0.5.

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I present a single row to XGBoost in the form of a sparse DMatrix?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

This will work:

```
DMatrix dMatrix = new DMatrix(new long[] {0, 22},
    new int[] {1, 9, 19, 21, 24, 34, 36, 39, 42, 53, 56, 65, 69, 77, 86, 88, 92, 95, 102, 106, 117, 122}, 
    new float[] {1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f},
    DMatrix.SparseType.CSR, 123);
```

So in other words, to classify a single observation, `headers` should have 2 entries, 0 and number of non-zero indices (IA), `indices` is the list of indices (JA), `data` is the list of non-zero values (A), type is CSR in this case and the shapeParam is the total number of columns (123 in this case of agaricus.txt).